# Getting docker-machine to create host without tlsverify

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I'm trying to get docker-machine to create a host that doesn't use TLS verification. I can't seem to find a way to do this. Is there an easy way to do:

`docker-machine create -d=virtualbox [?????] node1`

that can bring up the host so that tls is not used at all?

[Update: shell command had docker create instead of docker-machine create...]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Allow Mac OS X docker client to connect to Docker without TLS auth
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo 'DOCKER_TLS=no' > /var/lib/boot2docker/profile"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo /etc/init.d/docker stop >/dev/null 2>&1 || sudo /etc/init.d/docker start"
```

Taken from https://github.com/deis/deis/issues/2230

Comment: I've seen that. Unfortunately, the project isn't using vagrant, and only docker-machine is used.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to do this out of the box. I ended up doing a normal box, and doing the following:

- For Windows, I renamed the docker.exe executable to dockerapp.exe, and added a docker.bat with the following contents:

`@echo off
docker.exe --tlsverify=false %*`

- For linux, etc. alias docker to docker --tlsverify=false

That's working for me. A bit ugly, but works.